# Jsoup Out of memory error after the crawler has worked for hours

Tags: java, jsoup

Well I made a crawler with Jsoup 1.8.1 . Yesterday I ran it, after 5-6 hours it gave out of memory exception. Today also same thing happened. It worked for hours and crawled 5000+ pages then gave out of memory exception.

at

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(page_url).timeout(10*1000).get();



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
at org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.consumeToAny(CharacterReader.java:133)
at org.jsoup.parser.TokeniserState$38.read(TokeniserState.java:779)
at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.read(Tokeniser.java:42)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java:47)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:41)
at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:55)
at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30)
at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:115)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:532)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:171)
at classes.CrawlPages.pageInfo(CrawlPages.java:88)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:67)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.processController(CrawlPages.java:70)
at classes.CrawlPages.readSeed(CrawlPages.java:41)
at classes.StartRun.main(StartRun.java:40)
```

Thing is that it is able to crawl the same pages easily again if I run the crawler again. I my case the exception is not page dependent. Page sizes are also below 200KB.

Is this because of the recursive function I am using or some memory thing I don't know about?

Comment: I am assuming that you are getting outofmemory error because you are storing all the data that you are crawling on the heap and after five hours of constantly adding data you run out of space.

Comment: The crawled data is indexed in database and I think the garbage collector should look things after that. I am not storing it in heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out the reason for java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with the help of Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool. It showed that the Database connection objects are growing. I have use static Connection variable and hoped that it would save memory but it didn't happened. So now I am removing a reference to all the unused database connections.
Although still I didn't do it the proper way but at-least it's not going out of memory now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that may fit some of your problems.

In my case, after scraping around 100Kwww I used to suffer memory problems, java heap, and so on, and the programs stopped always. I reviewed the code again and and again, following the best practices, closing the connections and finally I gave up and I took some help from the bash.

Basically I coded a bash script that runs java -jar myscraper.jar in order to scrap only 100Kwww. After that, when Java ends completetly of scrapping the first set of 100Kwww, the bash script starts the next set and so on.

Maybe not the best but for me the only way to scrap 4Mwww/day without having memory issues.

Comment: Do you mean 4 million web pages a day ?